# How to NOT cascade delete in a recursive relation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity that has a ManyToMany relationship with itself:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> friends;
}
```

How can I delete a user without deleting all of his friends? I cannot use cascading deletes obviously. If I try to delete the user without cascading I get a this error: "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally with `ManyToMany` we will **map data in different tables, and the delete won't create much of a problem.** I feel your case is different an you are having a self relationship. I think you need to use some other ways to perform this action.

`How can I delete a user without deleting all of his friends?` The below option is one of them.

Considering your special mapping, `List<User>` in `User`, you should be **only updating the mapping table references, and not deleting anything from the `User` table.** Because they may have some other `User` as friends and that can create problems.

Comment: sounds great, how do I do that without resorting to native queries?

Comment: what about **HQL**?I am not sure if it can be done with any options in the mapping.

Comment: HQL is just minimally better than the native queries. But I guess I'll have to resort to that. What with social networks these days this problem should crop up more often. But then the social data krakens don't like to delete data once collected I guess

Comment: There are things that **you have to do with HQL and it there for that reason.** Upvote / accept answers if it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i don't think when using cascading hibernate tries to delete the friends, it should normally just delete the link between 2 users that is stored in another table.

This is why you have a constraint violation if you do not cascade because the link (U1,U2), which have foreign key constreints on both users, still exist while you try to delete one of the 2 users.

Comment: @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) -> this deletes the relation and the users, I just checked that again.

Comment: no problem, thanks anyway for trying to help. It may turn out (see below) that I cannot use annotations to fix this

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete a user you have to remove this user from the `friends` lists of all other users, because in the database these references are foreign keys. This removal cannot be done automatically, i.e. with an annotation.